# Making py.test, coverage and tox work together: __init__.py in tests folder?

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest, coverage.py, tox

I'm having a weird problem with `tox`, `py.test`, `coverage` and `pytest-cov`: when `py.test` with the `--cov` option is launched from `tox`, it seems to require an `__init__.py` file in the `tests` folder which is not immediately obvious.

While writing this post, I have kind of solved the initial problem by adding the aforesaid `tests/__init__.py`, but to this moment I don't fully understand why exactly it works or doesn't work, so I'm still asking for help. Please see below for details.

I've found a related question on SO but it only makes it more confusing because the answer seems to be opposite to what I've figured out so far:
[`py.test` and `__init__.py` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244277/py-test-and-init-py-files)

See also the official docs here: [py.test - Good Integration Practices](https://pytest.org/latest/goodpractices.html) (the very bottom of the page).

---

Simplified project structure:

```
setup.py
tox.ini
.coveragerc
project/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
    tests/
        __init__.py (optional, an empty file)
        test_module1.py
        test_module2.py
```

---

Relevant part of `tox.ini`:

```
[testenv:check]
commands = py.test --cov=project --cov-report=term
deps =
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov

[pytest]
python_files = test_*.py
norecursedirs = .tox
```

---

Relevant part of `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
branch = True
omit = project/tests/*
```

---

Now, the results:

- `py.test --cov=project --cov-report=term` run from project root => correct coverage whether `tests/__init__.py` file is present or not.
- `tox -e check` without `tests/__init__.py` => the tests are discovered and run, but I get a warning "Coverage.py warning: No data was collected." and the coverage is 0% for all modules
- `tox -e check` with `tests/__init__.py` => correct coverage again.

It's not immediately obvious to me why the `tests/__init__.py` file has to be there (adding this empty file solved the initial problem) for the `tox` run, but it doesn't matter when you run the tests/coverage manually. Any ideas?

Comment: See http://lists.idyll.org/pipermail/testing-in-python/2014-November/006224.html on how you should check coverage with tox.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `--cov {envsitepackagesdir}/<your-package-name>` in tox.ini.

Comment: And you have to have at least tox 1.6.1, else it isn't processed correctly

Comment: Worked for me until I added `tests/__init__.py` for unrelated reasons. Then I had to remove `{envsitepackagesdir}/`. Go figure...

Answer (score 4):

See: 
[Using py.test with coverage doesn't include imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404716/using-py-test-with-coverage-doesnt-include-imports)

I got rid of using `pytest-cov` and run `coverage` outright instead..

Also noticed with `pytest`, I did need the blank `__init__.py` in my test directory to function correctly. There is probably a reason for it somewhere.

I realize this is a couple of years old, but in case someone else comes across this..

Comment: adding the `__init__.py` means you're importing your source file and not the package installed by tox