# standalone py.test (ignore __init__.py files)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I have a simple python module (let's call it M1) which is standalone (the only import is to `collections`), inside a package containing ugliness. Part of the ugliness is in the package's `__init__.py` file. But M1 is nice and clean, and contains some test functions for use with py.test.

Now, I would like to test M1 and ignore all the ugliness. But py.test wants to run `__init__.py` -- **is there any way I can prevent this?** I really can't fix the `__init__.py` file at this time, and I want to keep my test functions contained right alongside the M1 module contents itself.

I've already read this SO question: [`py.test` and `__init__.py` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244277/py-test-and-init-py-files)  which explains the issue but offers no solution.

---

my `__init__.py` file looks something like this; it's just promoting items into package scope:

```
from .M1 import CleanThing1, CleanThing2
from .Evil1 import UglyThing1, UglyThing2
```

and the problem is that the Evil1 module requires some PYTHONPATH hackery to execute properly, and when I run

```
py.test mymodule/M1.py
```

it fails because of the Evil1 module. But I just want to test the M1 module right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `__init__.py` file aware of py.test as described [here](http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#detect-if-running-from-within-a-pytest-run).

So basically create a `mymodule/conftest.py` file with the following content

```
def pytest_configure(config):
    import sys
    sys._called_from_test = True

def pytest_unconfigure(config):
    del sys._called_from_test
```

and in the `__init__.py` file simply check if you are inside the py.test session like

```
import sys
if hasattr(sys, '_called_from_test'):
    # called from within a test run
    pass
else:
    # failing imports
    from .M1 import CleanThing1, CleanThing2
    from .Evil1 import UglyThing1, UglyThing2
```

This way I could run `py.test mymodule/M1.py` without the import errors.

The package structure now looks like (I hope that resembles your structure)

```
package
   |   
   |- __init__.py
   |- mymodule/
         |- M1.py
         |- conftest.py
```

Comment: how do you create a mymodule/conftest.py? My module name is M1.py (it's a module, not a package)... would I have to create M1/conftest.py?

Comment: what do you mean by how to create the conftest.py file? I've add a package structure to my answer, hope this resembles yours.

Comment: oh, thanks. The drawing really helps! It was a problem in terminology; if I understand Python correctly, your "mymodule" should really be a subpackage. Or I am misunderstanding the terminology.

Comment: You are totally right, sorry for the wrong terminology. I was just referring to your `py.test mymodule/M1.py` call.

Answer (score 0):

It's not py.test that wants to run `__init.py__`, but the Python interpreter. The rule that `__init__.py` is executed is part of the Python language definition, and any way around it will necessarily be a hack.

In this case, I suggest that you definte a stubbed `Evil1` module of your own, and let `M1` import that one instead.