# "File not found" using manage.py with pytest-django

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I have a Django project in which certain environment variables are set in `manage.py` which later serve as the values defined in `settings.py`. Therefore, in order to run [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I'd like to run `manage.py` first.

I'm trying to follow the instructions in https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-manage-py-test-with-pytest-django, but I'm running into an unexpected error. I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── lucy
│   ├── settings
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── development.py
    │   ├── production.py
│   └── staging.py
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── lucy_web
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── actions.py
│   ├── admin
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── fixtures
│   ├── forms
│   ├── lib
│   ├── management
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models
│   ├── runner.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── templatetags
│   ├── tests
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views
├── manage.py
├── pytest.ini
```

The contents of `runner.py` are taken exactly from the FAQ:

```
class PytestTestRunner(object):
    """Runs pytest to discover and run tests."""

    def __init__(self, verbosity=1, failfast=False, keepdb=False, **kwargs):
        self.verbosity = verbosity
        self.failfast = failfast
        self.keepdb = keepdb

    def run_tests(self, test_labels):
        """Run pytest and return the exitcode.

        It translates some of Django's test command option to pytest's.
        """
        import pytest

        argv = []
        if self.verbosity == 0:
            argv.append('--quiet')
        if self.verbosity == 2:
            argv.append('--verbose')
        if self.verbosity == 3:
            argv.append('-vv')
        if self.failfast:
            argv.append('--exitfirst')
        if self.keepdb:
            argv.append('--reuse-db')

        argv.extend(test_labels)
        return pytest.main(argv)
```

Finally, in `lucy/settings/base.py` I add the following line:

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'lucy_web.runner.PytestTestRunner'
```

Finally, the `pytest.ini` file is as in the example in the docs:

```
# -- FILE: pytest.ini (or tox.ini)
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = lucy.settings.production
# -- recommended but optional:
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

The problem is that `pytest` doesn't seem able to find the tests. If I run the command

```
python manage.py test lucy_web.tests
```

I get

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py test lucy_web.tests
============================================ test session starts ============================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy/lucy-web, inifile: pytest.ini

======================================= no tests ran in 0.00 seconds ========================================
ERROR: file not found: lucy_web.tests
```

However, if I comment out the `TEST_RUNNER` line in `base.py` and run the same command, the tests run successfully:

```
(venv) Kurts-MacBook-Pro:lucy-web kurtpeek$ python manage.py test lucy_web.tests
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
....E.F................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 23 tests in 15.974s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to put `runner.py` in a different location?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of `__init__.py`

I experienced a similar situation when using pytest. I deleted `__init__.py` in tests dir and it tested well.

It's little bit different situation, but I hope this helps.

> links that I got help.
>
> https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/pythonpath.html
>
> [`py.test` and `__init__.py` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244277/py-test-and-init-py-files)